# Cannot zoom image ( high resolution ) on ios 7

Tags: image, ios7, zooming

I have iPad 3, JB, version 7.0.4. Since I updated my iPad to ios 7, my picture ( PNG ) got blur when i tried to zoom in ( the resoluion of PNG 6000x4000) . Any fix for this problem, please help me !

Answer (score 0):

That's the problem with the image, what you can do.

Need to put right image (good quality image --> Smart Image). I don't think its problem with the iOS 7.

If I am thinking wrong, please give me more details of your issue.